# what is the best SQL for this scenario

Tags: sql

i have a table that has the following columns:

```
Team
Region
Person
Name
```

and i want a SQL report to produce one row for each team / region (groupby Team, Region) combination and also show me a column of total count of people that exist for that Team and Region.  One suggestion was to have a column with a value of 1 to them do a sum on that columns but there must be a simpler solution.  How can i do a count on people in this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  Team,
  Region,
  count(distinct Person)
from mytable
group by 1,2
```

Comment: I personally prefer naming my group-bys (so `group by Team, Region` instead of `1, 2`).

Answer (score 0):

```
select Team,
       Region,
       count(*) as PersonCount
from YourTable
group by Team, Region
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Team, Region, COUNT(*)
  FROM Table
  GROUP BY Team, Region
```

Should work just fine, unless i'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Team, Region, Count(Team) as PeopleCount 
from YourTable 
group by Team, Region
```

should do it. Note that some may suggest Count(all). Don't get used to using Count(all) IMO is a bad practice. If your have an index column in your table always use that in Count() wherever applicable. Then your query will be much faster since theres a possibility that depending on how the indexes are created, your query may end up using the index only and not touch the table.